# Store filtering using int not reflecting query

Tags: rally

I have the following filters:

```
var iterationFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
            property: 'Iteration',
            operation: '=',
            value: this.selectedIteration
        });

        var containsTestCaseFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
                property: 'TestCaseCount',
                operation: '>',
                value: '0'
        });
        var consolidatedFilter = iterationFilter.and(containsTestCaseFilter);
```

When I `console.log("filter: ", consolidatedFilter.toString();` I get the following output

filter:  ((Iteration = "/iteration/34300198519") AND (TestCaseCount = 0))

I would expect this to return the 2nd part as (TestCaseCount > 0). Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `operator` rather than `operation`.  The default value is '=' for filter operators which is why you're getting that behavior.

```
var containsTestCaseFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
    property: 'TestCaseCount',
    operator: '>',
    value: '0'
});
```